# Does the Personalistic Norm apply to Divine Persons?

Tags: trinity, angels, persons-of-the-trinity, john-paul-ii, personalism

St. Pope John Paul II would be wont to say:

> "the person is a good towards which the only proper and adequate attitude is love."

but in this sense, does "person" equally apply to the Divine Persons of the Holy Trinity, angels or humans as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any being that has the quality of personhood should be treated with love. It matters not whether we conceive of God as three persons or one. God is a person (or persons) who loves each human being and desires a reciprocal relation with us.

Loving God as the Father is natural. So is loving God as the Son for those who have a personal relationship with Jesus. Loving God as the Holy Spirit is less definite. [St. Teresa of Avila](https://schoolofmary.org/st-teresa-of-avila-the-necessity-of-mental-prayer/) spoke of prayer being "‘in Christ’, ‘before the Father’ and ‘through the Holy Spirit.’" So we may consider that in a trinitarian context, the Divine Persons are not necessarily adored separately terms of the give and take of love with the believer. In terms of the Holy Spirit's personhood, it is interesting in this context to consider John Paul's reflection on the connection between Mary and the Holy Spirit's regenerative function:

> In the Constitution Lumen Gentium the Second Vatican Council... she
> [Mary] who in the midst of the disciples in the upper room devoted
> herself to prayer, is the mother of the Son, predestined by God to be
> “the first-born among many brethren” (cf. Rom 8:29). The Council
> however adds that she herself cooperated “in the regeneration and
> formation” of these “brethren” of Christ, with her motherly love. The
> Church in her turn from the day of Pentecost “by her preaching brings
> forth to a new and immortal life the sons who are born to her in
> baptism, who are conceived of the Holy Spirit and born of God” (LG
> 64). The Church, therefore, by becoming herself a mother in this way,
> looks to the mother of Christ as her model. [Catechesis of Pope John Paul II on the
> Holy
> Spirit](https://schoolofmary.org/catechesis-of-pope-john-paul-ii-on-the-holy-spirit/)

One expression of personal love for the Holy Spirit may be seen in the Protestant hymn "Sweet, Sweet Spirit," where our love for the Spirit is returned in the form of praise.

```
    Sweet Holy Spirit, Sweet heavenly Dove,
Stay right here with us, filling us with Your love.
And for these blessings we lift our hearts in praise;
Without a doubt we'll know that we have been revived,
When we shall leave this place.
```

**Angels can be a problem**

Admittedly we run into problems when we consider angels, especially fallen ones. Are we to love even Satan? I would say ultimately yes, if we take Jesus' admonition of "love your enemy" seriously. I realize this position has many pitfalls, but for me, it is the only sensible response both to the Pope's declaration and Jesus' command. As a reminder:

> You have heard that it was said, ‘You shall love your neighbor and
> hate your enemy.’  But I say to you: Love your enemies and pray for
> those who persecute you, so that you may be children of your Father in
> heaven, for he makes his sun rise on the evil and on the good and
> sends rain on the righteous and on the unrighteous... Be perfect,
> therefore, as your heavenly Father is perfect. (Mt. 5)

**It's relatively easy to love Divine Persons, because they love us and are not tainted by evil. God is love, and love is not a one-way proposition. As God's children, created in the divine image, we naturally return God's love. Loving angelic beings is problematic if they have fallen, but not out of the question.**

Comment: Even harder than loving the prince of darkness is thinking of him as a good.  I entirely wasn't thinking of fallen angels when I wrote the question, but this is a very good point (and hard to swallow!)